# Comparing day and week prices and getting cheapest

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm trying to get the lowest price of an object. Problem is there can be daily and weekly prices. So when searching for the cheapest price i have to multiply the day price time 7 and compare to the week price to get the cheapest.
It can also happen that an object has week prices only or day prices only (or no prices at all).

BTW: It has to be such a subselect query, cause i have some more WHERE queries following later.

```
Pricetable
id  price   type    oid
1   10      d       1
2   12      d       2
3   70      w       1
4   80      w       2

Objects
id  name
1   house1
2   house2
```

This is what i'm using but its not working correctly. When the day price*7 is bigger that the week price it still gives me the day price.

```
SELECT p.oid, p.price, p.id, p.type FROM Pricetable p INNER JOIN (    
SELECT oid, MIN(IF(type="w",price, price*7)) AS price, id, type
    FROM Pricetable     
    GROUP BY oid 
) p2 ON p.oid = p2.oid AND p.id= p2.id
```

Comment: Have you tried a LEFT JOIN instead of an INNER JOIN? Not sure if it would work but my spidey sense is tingling :)

Comment: Your ON conditions don't look correct. How do the tables relate?

Comment: Pricetable.oid=Objects.id

Comment: Then it should be `ON p.id = p2.oid`. Skip the second condition.

Comment: Not sure about that. He's joining price `p` with price `p2` so surely he wants `p.id = p2.id`? I'd say the `p.oid = p2.oid` is redundant, though.

Comment: `SELECT id .. GROUP BY oid` will not work. Gordons second query is the solution.

Comment: I'd leave out `id` from the `SELECT` clause of the inner query and add `type` to the `GROUP BY` clause too

Comment: @DougMcLean Adding `type` to the `GROUP BY` will return two rows per `oid`. That wouldn't make sense. `(oid, type)` is probably UNIQUE.

Comment: @PaulSpiegel yes sorry you're quite right. Still the problem lies with the `id` and `type` fields being present in the inner `SELECT` but ignored by the `GROUP BY`. Running that inner query by itself shows that the wrong `id` and `type` are returned for `oid` 2.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your query should work to get the minimum *price*.  However, it should be written as:

```
SELECT oid, MIN(CASE WHEN type = 'w' THEN price ELSE 7*price END) AS price
FROM Pricetable     
GROUP BY oid ;
```

If you want other values from row with the minimum price, then you need more logic.  How about this?

```
SELECT pt.*oid, MIN(CASE WHEN type = 'w' THEN price ELSE 7*price END) AS price
FROM Pricetable pt
WHERE pt.id = (SELECT pt2.id
               FROM PriceTable pt2
               WHERE pt2.oid = pt.oid
               ORDER BY (CASE WHEN pt2.type = 'w' THEN pt2.price ELSE 7*pt2.price END)
               LIMIT 1
              );
```

Comment: does the first query miss a *7 multiplicator?

Comment: Yes Mike was missing the `7*`

Comment: last question: why use CASE instead of IF ?

Comment: @Mike . . . `CASE` is ANSI standard and available in all serious databases.

Answer (score 0):

You'll need a sub-select with some sort of ranking to get the cheapest price.

Check https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/13703/get-the-rank-of-a-user-in-a-score-table That should get you on the right track.

I don't have access to MySQL right now, and it's a bit different than MSSQL. But that link should set you on the path.